# Слайдер из элементов во втором активити

Tags: android

Есть MainActivity в котором выведен RecyclerView. В нем отображаются названия статей и картинка статьи. Также есть второй активити, в котором отображается выбранная статья. На данный момент во втором активити нет слайдера как внизу на картинке я указал просто обычный активити с контентом. Я хочу во втором активити сделать слайдер. Т.е. основная часть занята контентом выбранной статьи, а ниже как показано на картинке отображается слайдер из картинок элементов. Нажимая на соответствующую картинку контент меняется, а также две кнопки для перелистывания слайдера. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать второе активити? Т.е. Я думаю что там должны быть фрагменты, а дальше куда двигаться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

я бы воспользовался [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView). нужно будет помнить позицию каждого элемента и при нажатии кнопки скроллить на 1 позицию влево или вправо по [ScrollTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#scrollTo(int,%20int)) или [SmoothScrollTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#smoothScrollTo(int,%20int)). При нажатии конерктной картинки надо не забывать скроллить список к её позиции.

Answer (score 0):

У андроида есть [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) для таких целей.

Comment: Мне нужно прокручивать не весь экран, а только картинки внизу. Для этого подойдет ViewPager? Хотя можно и весь экран прокручивать, но тогда нужно чтобы внизу картинки тоже прокручивались по мере перелистывания контента. И возможность отдельно прокручивать картинки внизу в слайдере